# Gitlab commit author is different than pipeline author (triggerer)

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, commit, git-commit

I think there was a previous git account on my computer, I tried to uninstall Git and re-install it and did the following commands to configure it :

git config --global user.name "myusername"
git config --global user.email myemail

But I always get a wrong user as pipeline triggerer :
[image]

What can I do ?

Thanks

Update 1 : I get the correct user name as commit author, the problem is only on pipelines.

Comment: Is it a complex build like a trigger build or something? Or is this just a commit build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **credentials** used to push determine the pipeline user, not the commit author. Otherwise, you could arbitrarily impersonate users for pipelines just by changing the commit author. The commit author has no bearing on the pipeline "triggered by" user.

You are probably still using the SSH key or username/password to your other "wrong" account when pushing to GitLab or otherwise triggering the pipeline. You will need to update your git ssh or https authentication to use the intended account.